# I get this error i get after upgrading flutter to the latest version

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error after upgrading flutter. please how can i fix it.

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode... Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found   at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)     at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.(ZipFile.java:1308)     at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:733)   at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)  at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:248)     at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:177)     at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:191)     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)   at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)   at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)   at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)   at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)   at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)     at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61) Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using Windows, Go to the root directory C:\Users\YourUser and locate the hidden .gradle folder and delete it.
and then run your app connected to an Android emulator or device, don't cancel and make have a stable internet connection, this will download fresh Gradle

If the problem persists, Can you please provide your flutter doctor -v and flutter run --verbose logs, and a minimal complete reproducible code sample